# Why isn't MessagingCenter.Subscribe working?

Tags: xamarin.forms

In Xamarin forms, I `Subscribe` in `OnAppearing` and `Unsubscribe` in `OnDisappearing`. But it still calling the callback for every instance.

```
protected override void OnAppearing(){
   if (isGoingBack)
        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<PhoneNumberVerificationPajModal, string>(this, "Phone.Verify", codeSendRequest);
}

protected override void OnDisappearing(){
    if (isGoingBack)
        MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<PhoneNumberVerificationPajModal>(this, "Phone.Verify");
}
```

Truth is calling `Unsubscribe` works. But, in my code I have a condition when the click on a button I open a `Page`. As that page is the one sending the message, when the user click the button I set `isGoingBack = false`. When I Press the back button and coming back to the page, I can Unsubscribe and Subscribe get called. But going to the next the callback event get call the same number of time I created a new page. But the truth is I `Unsubscribe` whenever I leave the page.

Comment: I'd suggest Subscribing in the constructor and unsubscribe only on `isGoingBack`

Comment: I already try that. The problem is the user can go back and come back anytime he wants to the page. So, whenever the user come to the page, the `Page` will subscribe. And when Going back unsubscribe. That was supposed to work. Looks like whenever Page Subscribes again `MessagingCenter` has a cache or count and bind all the other subscriber calls again for `this`.

Comment: When you say call back for every instance what does that mean exactly?

Comment: @FreakyAli This means every time I enter the page, `MessagingCenter.send()` call the subscriber that *every time*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your sample you are not passing the arg type to the unsubscribe method

try unsubscribing with the same type parameter you are subscribing with.

so instead of

```
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<PhoneNumberVerificationPajModal>(this, "Phone.Verify");
```

try

```
MessagingCenter.Unsubscribe<PhoneNumberVerificationPajModal, string>(this, "Phone.Verify");
```

Comment: Yep. I missed the extra generic type.